# Why does push notification replaces prior notification when using minishlink/webpush?

Tags: php, push-notification, notifications, web-push

I went though some other enquiries regarding replaced notification but i haven't found my answer yet. Im using minishlink/webpush to send push notification through web browser but the prior notification keeps getting replaced and the upcoming notification is not prompt / does not pop up for user, rather it replaces the prior notification in the notification panel. I added few unique identifier but it still isn't working

heres my PushNotificationService class

```
<?php

namespace common\components;

use Minishlink\WebPush\WebPush;
use Minishlink\WebPush\Subscription;
use frontend\models\notification\UserSubscriptions;
use Exception;

class PushNotificationService {

public static function sendNotificationToUser($userId, $title, $message, $url) {
    // VAPID keys (generated earlier)
    $publicKey = 'BIMBZr3K1YdaKwVSahjdgdrgz1aafesfsfBco8Tte496whQnaEvVvRTkckuYlAfwSPrvEcLvmGQB-Zy2YbEj1UM';
    $privateKey = '9tjiAzpQ5sdw0KUOnj-yWA9alTYBC9bgku9orpql9uI';

    // Retrieve subscription from the database
    $userSubscription = UserSubscriptions::find()->where(['user_id' => $userId])->all();
    if ($userSubscription) {
        // Create the WebPush instance
        $webPush = new WebPush([
            'VAPID' => [
                'subject' => 'mailto:mail@mail.com',
                'publicKey' => $publicKey,
                'privateKey' => $privateKey,
            ],
        ]);

        foreach ((array) $userSubscription as $sendNotification) {
            $subscription = Subscription::create(json_decode($sendNotification->subscription, true));
            $uniqId = uniqid();

            // Prepare the payload with a timestamp and tag
            $payload = json_encode([
                'title' => $title,
                'message' => $message,
                'icon' => "/images/logo-255x255.png",
                'tag' => "my-notification-$uniqId",
                'timestamp' => time(),
                'url' => '//www.google.com',
                'data' => [
                    'notificationId' => $uniqId,
                ],
                'requireInteraction' => true,
                'urgency' => 'high',
            ]);

            // Send the notification
            if ($webPush->sendOneNotification($subscription, $payload)) {
                \common\models\myTools\Mydebug::dumpFileA("Success");
            } else {
                \common\models\myTools\Mydebug::dumpFileA("Error");
            }
        }

        // Flush messages (actually send them)
        $webPush->flush();
    }
}

}
```

heres my push eventlistener in service worker

```
self.addEventListener('push', event => {
const data = event.data.json();

const options = {
    body: data.message,
    icon: data.icon,
    tag: data.tag,
    data: {
        notificationId: data.data.notificationId,
    },
    requireInteraction: data.requireInteraction,
    urgency: data.urgency
};

event.waitUntil(
        self.registration.showNotification(data.title, options)
        );
});
```

Comment: Can you tell what error you receive after placing the Uniqid in tag?

Comment: @HassaanAli ive edited my payload as such in the question above and included the push listener. I cant tell if there is an error or not but i checked the data received by push event listener and its all there. Notification is pushed but if i don't interact(click/clear the previous notification, i will not receive a pop-up for the new notification, it will straight replace the previous one in notification panel without user knowing.